# java try except returning after try and catch

Tags: java, io

I have the following function body

```
String f(filename){
   BufferredReader br = null;
   try{..}
   catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
   }

}
```

Inside the try block I try to open the file and do something with it. At the end of the try block I return a string. The program does not compile.

So, I initialize a string variable before the try block, manipulate the variable inside the try block and return it after the catch block. Is this the right way to do it? My question is why does the compiler not allow me to directly return the string inside they `try` block. Furthermore, I've tried to close the file by doing `br.close()` after the catch blockand the program does not compile too saying I need to handel an `IOException`, so I had to close the file inside the try block.

Is this also the write way to do it? To open and close the file both inside the try block.

Comment: what makes you think it doesn't allow that? the point is, it needs a return statement for each possible scenario. either that, or you need to throw an exception in your catch block

Comment: If you are using java 7+, you can use try-with-resource blocks. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: oh, so if an exception occurs, the program still continues onto the next line. I see. What about closing the file. Should I do it inside the try block?

Comment: No it doesn't continue onto the next line. It jumps to the catch block. Post your real code in the question.

Comment: You should do that inside the finally-block.

Comment: "_so if an exception occurs, the program still continues onto the next line_" Wrong. On exception it jumps to catch/finally.

Comment: Please post the code that doesn't compile and the error message.

Comment: I meant after the exception is caught. It proceeds to what is after the catch block

Comment: @matt yes, unless you re-throw it, or remove the try-catch and add a throws to the method signature

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: So you have a piece of code that doesn't compile, but instead of showing us exactly that code, you decided to put up parts of the code and lengthy explanations. May I ask: why?

Comment: it is much easier to help you if you post the whole method

Comment: Sorry. The code compiles when I made the changes described above. I wanted to ask specific questions also described above.

Answer (score 1):

You must return some value from function in any possible case (or throw exception), so this code isn't compiled:

```
String f(filename){
   BufferredReader br = null;
   try{
     ...
     return s;
   }
   catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace(); // what is return from function in this case?  
   }
}
```

You should use following code

```
String f(filename){
   BufferredReader br = null;
   try{
     ...
     return s;
   }
   catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return null; // or return "";
}
```

or

```
String f(filename){
   BufferredReader br = null;
   try{
     ...
     return s;
   }
   catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
       throw new RuntimeException(e);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, method 2 was how I did it. I also did br.close() inside the try block. Is this the way to go or does the construct automatically close the file for me.

Comment: @matt search for try-with-resources

Comment: I know about that, but it is a little too complicated and I do not wish to implement it for now. I would like to know if I should do br.close() inside the try block. Since I could not do it after the catch block.